# editing json in internal storage deletes array

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Im trying to change a single value of my json that is located in the internal storage, the json has 222 objects, but somehow they are all deleted but one when i try to change a value. Does anyone know why this is? I am trying to change the value like this:

```
 fun writeJsonToInternalStorage(pos: Int) {
        try {
            val file = File(this.filesDir, "stempel.json")


            if (file.exists()) {
                val jsonString = file.readText()
                var jsonarr = JSONArray(jsonString)
                var jsonObject = jsonarr.getJSONObject(pos)
                jsonObject.put("sammelstatus",1)
                file.writeText(jsonObject.toString())
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

if i do this it changes from this:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "sname": "Eckertalsperre (Staumauer)",
      "location": "N51.84165 E10.57998",
      "sammelstatus": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "sname": "Scharfenstein (Rangerstation)",
      "location": "N51.83017 E10.60277",
      "sammelstatus": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 222,
      "sname": "Bergbaulehrpfad Wettelrode",
      "location": "N51.52038 E11.27694",
      "sammelstatus": 0
    }
  ]
```

to this:

```
{"id":222,"sname":"Bergbaulehrpfad Wettelrode","location":"N51.52038 E11.27694","sammelstatus":0}
```

Ive asked chatgpt why this is, but he cant help me eather. As seen with these "[]" my Json should be an array i think.

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
                val jsonString = file.readText()
                var jsonarr = JSONArray(jsonString)
```

This code is reading in a JSON **array**.

```kotlin
                var jsonObject = jsonarr.getJSONObject(pos)
                jsonObject.put("sammelstatus",1)
                file.writeText(jsonObject.toString())
```

This code is writing out a JSON **object**, one that you obtained from that JSON array that you read in.

So, try:

```kotlin
                var jsonObject = jsonarr.getJSONObject(pos)
                jsonObject.put("sammelstatus",1)
                file.writeText(jsonarr.toString())
```

This modifies a JSON object inside that JSON array, but then writes out the array.